# I must not add row with 2 same values in columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Can I enter a rule when creating a table so that I, as an author, can't add a review to a product I've already reviewed?
I've been thinking about triggers, but I don't know exactly how to set it. In the workbench I can check it via this code:

```
declare
  pocet number := 0;
begin
  SELECT COUNT(a."id_recenze")
INTO pocet
FROM "recenze" a
INNER JOIN (SELECT "id_komponenty", "id_autora"
            FROM "recenze"
            GROUP BY "id_komponenty", "id_autora"
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b
ON a."id_komponenty" = b."id_komponenty" AND a."id_autora" = b."id_autora";

  if pocet > 2 then
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Nesmite vytvaret recenzi na komponentu, u ktere jste uz recenzoval');
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Vysledek je v poradku');
  end if;
end;
```

But I don't want to be able to create these records.

Can someone help me, how i can do it?
I use APEX by Oracle.

EDIT: (24.4. 10:35)

---

In a nutshell, i don't want records, where id_autora & id_komponenty are more times. For example i don't want this:

```
id_recenze(PK) id_autora id_komponenty
    1             2           3
    2             2           3
```

Answer (score 1):

After your explanation I see you could still use a unique index but you want to create it on id_komponenty and id_autora.  That would throw an error if you tried to add a duplicate.

But I see from your code that you are trying to update with the most recent values if it's duplicated.  In that case I would abandon the idea of the index and the trigger, and I would replace the INSERT statement (not shown) with Oracle's MERGE statement.  This allows a simultaneous logic for insert and update, plus you get to define the criteria when you do either.  It would look something like:

```
    MERGE INTO recenze r 
    USING (Select <newid_komponenty> AS newk
                              ,<newid_autora AS newa> from Dual) n
      ON (r.id_komponenty=n.newk And r.id_autora=n.newa)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET {your update logic here}
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT {your insert logic here}
```

Personally, I try to stay away from triggers when there are other solutions available.  By altering your Insert statement to this Merge you get the same effect with one less DB object to keep track of and maintain.

Comment: i have id_recenze like unique, maybe i explain the problem bad way. Look edit :)

Answer (score -2):

I get it.

```
    CREATE TRIGGER "nesmiPridat" BEFORE INSERT ON "recenze"
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
DECLARE pocet INT(2);
DECLARE smazat INT(2);

SET pocet := (SELECT COUNT("id_recenze") FROM "recenze" WHERE (NEW."id_autora" = "id_autora") AND (NEW."id_komponenty" = "id_komponenty"));
SET smazat :=(SELECT "id_recenze" FROM "recenze" WHERE (NEW."id_autora" = "id_autora") AND (NEW."id_komponenty" = "id_komponenty"));

IF (pocet > 0) THEN
DELETE FROM "recenze" WHERE smazat."id_recenze" = NEW."id_recenze";
END IF;

END;
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax in Oracle PL/SQL.